# Fast Matrix Lookup

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I need to compute a matrix lookup (see below) as quickly as possible.

totquadpoint and nbval.Wepast are fixed scalars around 200 each (dimension of vectors flnewcumyieldpos and flneweta1pos). 
nexttsteppenal is a 3D matrix (dimensions at least 80 * 80 * 80)

Since I need to do the operation below many times (this double loop is itself in a triple nested loop), I need to make it quick. Is there a way to make it quicker than what is written below ? If ever it's not possible in Matlab, what type of gain can I expect if I try to make that piece of code in Java/C ?

--------CODE :-----------------

```
for k=1:totquadpoint
    nexttsteppenalYA1dd=nexttsteppenal(flnewcumyieldpos(k),flneweta1pos(k),:);
    nexttsteppenalYA1du=nexttsteppenal(upflnewcumyieldpos(k),flneweta1pos(k),:);
    nexttsteppenalYA1ud=nexttsteppenal(flnewcumyieldpos(k),upflneweta1pos(k),:);
    nexttsteppenalYA1uu=nexttsteppenal(upflnewcumyieldpos(k),upflneweta1pos(k),:);

    flnewportvalposvec=flnewportvalpos(k,:);
    upflnewportvalposvec=upflnewportvalpos(k,:);

    for we=1:nbval.Wepast                                                
        penddd(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1dd(flnewportvalposvec(we));
        penddu(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1dd(upflnewportvalposvec(we));
        pendud(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1du(flnewportvalposvec(we));
        penduu(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1du(upflnewportvalposvec(we));

        penudd(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1ud(flnewportvalposvec(we));
        penudu(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1ud(upflnewportvalposvec(we));
        penuud(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1uu(flnewportvalposvec(we));
        penuuu(k,we)=nexttsteppenalYA1uu(upflnewportvalposvec(we));

    end
end
```

Comment: Please add data, so that one can reproduce your problem easily.

Comment: *shudder* I see that you use `explicitVariableNames`, but do they have to be so long?

Comment: @Jonas : I could make them shorter. Does the length of variables name affect the speed (or it's only to improve readability?)

Comment: @Andrey : is there a way I can upload data on this site? If not, I'll post code to generate random values for the matrix content of the appropriate size.

Comment: @FrédéricGodin please do (post the code)

Comment: @Andrey I posted the code for "simulated data" in tables below.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for w=1:n
    p(k,w)=d(f(w));
end
```

should be:

```
p(k,1:n)=d(f(1:n));
```

Or even better, when `n` is the length of `f`:

```
p(k,:)=d(f);
```

For the outer loop you will probably need `sub2ind()`.

Comment: I tried your idea with the following code (below), but this slows down the program (from 1.1sec to 1.5sec with tic/toc). I guess I gotta find another way. 

penddd=nexttsteppenal(sub2ind(size(nexttsteppenal),repmat(flnewcumyieldpos,1,nbval.Wepast),repmat(flneweta1pos,1,nbval.Wepast),flnewportvalpos));
etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable version of the code above with simulated values for the tables.
My problem is how to optimize the speed of the two nested for loops at the end (I need to run this loop maybe a million times).

```
quadpoints=800;
nbWe=100;

penddd=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penddu=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
pendud=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penduu=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penudd=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penudu=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penuud=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);
penuuu=zeros(quadpoints,nbWe);

nsp=rand(100,50,100);

ypos=min(sort(poissrnd(50,quadpoints,1),'ascend'),100);
uypos=min(ypos,100);
etapos=min(sort(poissrnd(25,quadpoints,1),'ascend'),50);
uetapos=min(etapos,50);
Vpos=min(sort(poissrnd(50,quadpoints,nbWe),'ascend'),100);
uVpos=min(Vpos,100);

for k=1:quadpoints
     nspdd=nsp(ypos(k),etapos(k),:);
     nspdu=nsp(uypos(k),etapos(k),:);
     nspud=nsp(ypos(k),uetapos(k),:);
     nspuu=nsp(uypos(k),uetapos(k),:);
     dVvec=Vpos(k,:);
     uVvec=uVpos(k,:);

      for we=1:nbWe
     penddd(k,we)=nspdd(dVvec(we));
         penddu(k,we)=nspdd(uVvec(we));
         pendud(k,we)=nspdu(dVvec(we));
         penduu(k,we)=nspdu(uVvec(we));
         penudd(k,we)=nspud(dVvec(we));
         penudu(k,we)=nspud(uVvec(we));
         penuud(k,we)=nspuu(dVvec(we));
         penuuu(k,we)=nspuu(uVvec(we));

      end
end
```